# MKMapView freeze when map setRegion

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone-developer-program

I'm trying to setRegion, but when i set the region, the map freeze and I can't move the map...

here is my code

```
 -(void) configurarZoomDoMapaComLatitude:(double)latitude eLongitude:(double)longitude {
_myMapView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
CLLocation *localizacao = [[CLLocation alloc]initWithLatitude:latitude longitude:longitude]; //regiao de ref. (usar localizacao atual)
double miles = 0.5; // quanto menor, mais próximo
double scalingFactor = ABS( (cos(2 * M_PI * localizacao.coordinate.latitude / 360.0) ));

MKCoordinateSpan span;
span.latitudeDelta = miles/69.0;
span.longitudeDelta = miles/(scalingFactor * 69.0);

MKCoordinateRegion region;
region.span = span;
region.center = localizacao.coordinate;
[_myMapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: If the map is freezing, is it because your app has crashed? If it's crashed, you should include the crash log.

Comment: @nevanking no...the app hasn't crashed...if I press any button in my app, it works...only the map is freezed

Comment: It's likely that setting the region isn't the cause of the map freezing. Try creating a different region and setting that region, then check if the map is still frozen.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I have solved this problem... I did a view in map add...I remove this and it works! Thx all